# itterating over a set of data - so that i fetch data from a site with beautiful-soup, panda and store it subsequently

Tags: python, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

i am currently workin on a sript to be able to scrape the data from the given website using Beautiful Soup and store it in a CSV format: the site 'https://schulen.bildung-rp.de' - a governmental site that lists schools.

**update:**  see a result-page here.

[image]

with the following dataset:

```
Kurzbezeichnung:    GY Ludwigshafen Carl-Bosch
Schulnummer:    50360
Anschrift:  Carl-Bosch-Gymnasium Ludwigshafen
Jägerstr. 9
67059 Ludwigshafen am Rhein
Telefon:    (0621)504430810
Telefax:    (0621)504430898
E-Mail: cbg(at)cbglu.de
Internet:   http://www.cbglu.de
Träger: Stadtverwaltung Ludwigshafen am Rhein
letzte Änderung:    15 Nov 2012 14:39:15 von 50360
```

well i am looking for the following things -( categories ) in the dataset:

```
Kurzbezeichnung:    
Schulnummer:
Anschrift:  
Telefon:
Telefax:
E-Mail: 
Internet:   
Träger:
```

subsequently i have to correct the code!

#well Here's an example code snippet that i am using as a starting point:

what is aimed: this code will extract data from the table on the above given website, and store it in both a CSV file (schools.csv) and a pandas dataframe (schools_pandas.csv).
note  that the table on the website contains seven columns or lemme say fieldnames = ['Kurzbezeichnung','Schulnummer','Anschrift', 'Telefon', 'Telefax', 'E-Mail','Internet', 'Träger').  ... but

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

# send a GET request to the target URL
url = 'https://schulen.bildung-rp.de'
response = requests.get(url)

# parse the HTML content using Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# find the table element containing the desired data
table = soup.find('table')

# extract the data from the table and store it in a list of dictionaries
data = []
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    if len(cols) == 7:
        # extract the desired columns and store them in a 

   # extract the desired columns and store them in a dictionary
        Kurzbezeichnung = cols[0].text.strip()
        Anschrift = cols[1].text.strip()
        Telefon: =  cols[2].text.strip()
        Telefax: = cols[3].text.strip()
        E-Mail: =  cols[4].text.strip()
        Internet = cols[5].text.strip()
        Träger =   cols[6]text.strip()
        data.append({'Kurzbezeichnung': school_name,
                     'Anschrift': school_type,
                     'Telefon': phonenumber,
                     'Telefax': faxnumber,
                     'E-Mail': mailadress   
                     'Internet': internet-adress,
                     'Träger': trager,})
                    
# store the data in a CSV file
with open('schools.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
fieldnames = ['Kurzbezeichnung','Schulnummer','Anschrift', 'Telefon', 'Telefax', 'E-Mail','Internet', 'Träger'] 

    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow(item)

# alternatively, load the data into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('schools_pandas.csv', index=False)
```

it does not store the data ... but the table structure  i think is correctly "reworked and treated" in the code -

well i think that the code is pretty complete hmmm  i think that i may need to modify the code accordingly a bit...

Comment: On the page I see table with 4 columns but the columns are `"Schulnummer"/"Kurzbezeichnung"/"PLZ"/"Datenschutz"`, not `School Name, School Type, City, and District`. Do I see the same table?

Comment: [As far as I can see] there's only one table at https://schulen.bildung-rp.de and you can save it to CSV as simply as `pd.read_html('https://schulen.bildung-rp.de')[0].to_csv('schools_pandas.csv', index=False)` [It *will* have different column than you seem to be looking for, as AndrejKesely noted, although you can probably figure out the Type from the first "word" in the Kurzbezeichnung column]

Comment: hello dear Andrej and Driftr95 - many thanks for the reply - youre right - i have added some explanation in the threadstart - and yes well i am looking for the following things -( categories ) in the dataset:

    Kurzbezeichnung: 
    Schulnummer: 
    Telefon:
    Telefax:
    E-Mail: 
    Internet: 
    Träger: 

subsequently i have to correct the code!... hopefully i manage that  - guess that this can be done... Driftr - did i get you right: can we save this to csv with your line?
i will digg deeper into all that... many  thanks for all your help here  - its outstanding ...

Comment: HI there i added some ideas and corrections  accordingly - but i have seen that even more corrections are necessary - i will have to do even more corrections....

Answer (score 1):

Note: you can reduce your code to

```py
# [import requests,bs,pd..]
#soup=BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://schulen.bildung-rp.de').content,'html.parser')
# fieldnames = ['Kurzbezeichnung','Schulnummer','Anschrift', 'Telefon',...] 
get_row = lambda tr: [c.text.strip() for c in tr.find_all('td')]
data_gen = (get_row(row) for row in soup.find('table').find_all('tr'))
data = [dict(zip(fieldnames, row)) for row in data_gen if len(row)==len(fieldnames)]
```

But unless you have a `fieldnames` containing exactly 6 names, the *`if len(row)==__`* condition [in either code - yours or mine] will keep `data` empty, because the table at [schulen.bildung-rp.de](https://schulen.bildung-rp.de) has exactly 6 columns <sup>(**[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwMm7.png)** *`['Schulart','Schulnummer', 'Kurzbezeichnung','Adresse','PLZ','Datenschutz']`*)</sup>, and unless `fieldnames` represents them, the column headers will not make much sense even if `data` is not empty.

---

> ***update**: see a result-page here.* <sup>**[[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAkNT.png)]**</sup>

> *well i am looking for the following things -( categories ) in the dataset... 'Kurzbezeichnung','Schulnummer','Anschrift','Telefon','Telefax','E-Mail','Internet','Träger'*

> ```py
> # send a GET request to the target URL
> url = 'https://schulen.bildung-rp.de'
> response = requests.get(url)
> ```

The screenshot added [and the data you want] ***are from another page***<sup>([///einzelanzeige.html?///D=50360](https://schulen.bildung-rp.de/einzelanzeige.html?tx_wfqbe_pi1%5Buid%5D=50360))</sup>, not from [schulen.bildung-rp.de](https://schulen.bildung-rp.de), although the links to the page with that data are there. To get to that data, you will have to request it from each individual school's page link by link.

Since the links are in the third column (`Kurzbezeichnung`) of the [schulen.bildung-rp.de](https://schulen.bildung-rp.de) table, you can get the links with [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) like:

```py
sl_sel='table#schulen tr td:first-child+td+td>a[href^="\/einzelanzeige.html?"]'
school_links = ['https://schulen.bildung-rp.de'+a['href'] for a in soup.select(sl_sel)]
```

or with `.find_all` like:

```py
checkHref = lambda h: isinstance(h,str) and h.startswith('/einzelanzeige.html?')
school_links = ['https://schulen.bildung-rp.de'+a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=checkHref)]
```

And below are 2 versions of a `get_school_details` which should be applied on loop to each URL in `school_links` to get each row of our final DataFrame.

---

#### Version 1: With `pandas.read_html`

Since the data at each school page is also in a `table` tag, one option would be to use `pd.read_html`, which would get you those exact 8 fields. <sup>(not 7 btw)</sup> [ **[view output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFjdX.png)** ]

```py
def get_school_details(school_link): 
    if not school_link.startswith('https://schulen.bildung-rp.de'):
        school_link = 'https://schulen.bildung-rp.de' + school_link
    return {k.strip(':').title(): v for k, v, *_ in 
            pd.read_html(school_link)[0].to_dict('split')['data']}
```

However, `pd.read_html` often clumps cell values into single-line strings without even spaces between separate lines, and you have less control over the data extracted.

---

#### Version 2: With `requests`+`BeautifulSoup`

Using `requests`+`BeautifulSoup` can be slower and won't be as simple, but you will be able to extract more data. [ **[view output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae9hr.png)** ]

```py
def get_school_details(school_link, typeFinder=lambda n:n.split()[0], sMsg=''):
    base_url = 'https://schulen.bildung-rp.de'
    if not school_link.startswith(base_url): school_link = base_url+school_link
    sSoup = BeautifulSoup((r:=requests.get(school_link)).content, 'html.parser')
    print(f'\r{sMsg}', rStatus:=f'<{r.status_code} {r.reason}> from {r.url}', end='')

    scName = sSoup.select_one('h1:has(~table)') 
    sDets = {'Schulname': scName.get_text(' ', strip=True)} if scName else {}

    carrier_link = None
    for row in sSoup.select('h1~table tr:has(td+td)'):
        k = ' '.join(row.find('td').get_text(' ').split()).rstrip(':').title()
        v = row.select_one('td+td').get_text(' ')

        if k.strip() == 'E-Mail': v = [''.join(v.replace('(at) ', '@').split())]
        else: v = [' '.join(l.split()) for l in v.splitlines() if l.strip()]

        if k.strip()=='Kurzbezeichnung': sDets['Schultyp'] = typeFinder(v[0]) if v else ''
        sDets[k.strip()] = '\n'.join(v)
    
    sDets['Schullink'] = school_link
    lRefs = {'Trägerlink': 'a[href^="/traeger.html?"]', 
             'osm_link':'a[href^="https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map="]',
             'dpo_link': f'a[href^="{base_url}/datenschutz.html?"]'}
    for k, s in lRefs.items():
        if (a:=sSoup.select_one(s.replace("/", "\\/"))): 
            sDets[k] = (base_url if k=='Trägerlink' else '') + a['href']

    return sDets if sDets else {'error_msg': f'Failed to scrape: {rStatus}'}
```

---

#### Scraping All Links

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

## function for scraping a single school link ##
# def get_school_details..... # [choose from above or define your own]

## fetching homepage to extract school links ##
url = 'https://schulen.bildung-rp.de' 
soup = BeautifulSoup((response:=requests.get(url)).content, 'html.parser')

## [ optional ] for finding school type ##
tInps = [(s, s.next) for s in soup.select('input[name="schart"][value]')]
sTyps=[(s['value'],sn.strip().title()) for s,sn in tInps if isinstance(sn,str)]
get_stypes = lambda abbr: ', '.join({v for k,v in sTyps if k in str(abbr).split()})

## collecting the individual school links ##
sl_sel='table#schulen tr td:first-child+td+td>a[href^="\/einzelanzeige.html?"]'
school_links = [a['href'] for a in soup.select(sl_sel)]
links_ct = len(school_links)

''' ## scraping all the school links and saving - version 1 (pandas) ##
df = pd.DataFrame([get_school_details(l) for l in school_links])
# df['Schultyp'] =  df['Kurzbezeichnung'].apply(get_stypes) ## [if you want to add it]
# df['Schullink'] = school_links ## [if you want to add it]
df.to_csv('schulen_bildung.csv', index=False)
'''

## scraping all the school links and saving - version 2 (req+bs) ##
data = [get_school_details(l, get_stypes, f'\r[{li} of {links_ct}] ') 
        for li, l in enumerate(school_links, 1)]
```

[image: opdf]

The screenshot above shows the results with version 2 of `get_school_details`, but you can see the full results with both versions in [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oroKd_TUYj90TxUbfj8_MVZm7tdfz2jrBIEPnMAPgDQ).

Comment: many thanks dear Drift95 for sharing your ideas and thoughts - this is really cool. And i am learning alot. Your explanation and the guidance is so awsome: Your great!! 
Your help is appreciated alot! Have agreat weekend!

Comment: hello dear Driftr95 - again this is so awesome - you have aawesome teaching style and i have gained lots of insights do your brilliant ideas: really i have learne alot from you - and your competence to solve problems. Dear Driftr95 one question left:  Could you perhaps have a look at this tiny script that i struggle with  - here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75828625/nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable-bs4-task-fails-permanently - i would be more than happy. - have a great weekend.  Yours Malaga

Answer (score 1):

I'd resort to using `pandas` mostly, as the data on the site is pretty well structured, so it shouldn't be hard to get it with minimal effort and then massage it a bit to the format you like.

**NOTE**: The servers are pretty slow, so you can access the `.csv` file thru my [onedrive link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArAg_nhR8Mj8gRQIR6IkYdOmaUsZ?e=sRUhSW), where you can find the output file with all the data.

**ANOTHER NOTE**: Please proofread the data, to see if that's *exactly* what you need.

Try this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

main_url = "https://schulen.bildung-rp.de"
columns_to_drop = [
    "letzte Änderung:",
]

with requests.Session() as s:
    anchors = (
        BeautifulSoup(s.get(main_url).content, "lxml")
        .select("#schulen > tbody > tr > td > a")
    )
    urls = [
        f'{main_url}{anchor["href"]}' for anchor in anchors
        if anchor["href"].startswith("/einzelanzeige")
    ]
    tables = [
        pd.read_html(s.get(url).text, flavor="lxml", index_col=0)[0].T
        for url in urls
    ]
    df = (
        pd
        .concat(tables, ignore_index=True)
        .drop(columns=columns_to_drop)
    )
    df["Anschrift:"].replace({"\xa0": " "}, regex=True, inplace=True)
    df.to_csv("daten_für_alle_schulen.csv", index=False)
```

This should get you a `.csv` file that looks something like this:

[image: ![Final Data Table Output]

Comment: many thanks dear Baduker for sharing your ideas and thoughts - this is really cool. And i am learning alot. Your great!!

Comment: hello dear baduker - again this is so awesome.  your ideas are brilliant - and i learn alot from you - and your competence to solve problems.  Could you perhaps have a look at this tiny script that i struggle with  - here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75828625/nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable-bs4-task-fails-permanently - i would be more than happy. - have a great day.  Yours Malaga

Comment: You already have two answers there. Also, you can just download the data in an Excel file straight from the site. No need to scrape the tables.